# Templated Point class of any dimension

Tags: c++, c++11, coordinate-system

I needed to make a point class for a term project that involved arbitrary dimensional points.  I came up with this, and I know that it works fine, but I'm looking to improve it so I can reuse it in the future.  Any criticisms or suggestions are very much appreciated.

```
#ifndef POINT_HPP
#define POINT_HPP

#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t D>
struct Point;

template <size_t D>
struct Point {
  Point(const std::initializer_list<double>& v) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (auto e : v) {
      coordinates_[i++] = e;
    }
  }

  explicit Point(const std::array<double, D>& arr) : coordinates_{arr} {}

  double operator[](size_t dimension) const { return coordinates_[dimension]; }
  Point<D>& operator=(const Point& other) {
    this->coordinates_ = other.coordinates_;
    return *this;
  }
  std::array<double, D> coordinates_;
};

/*
 * Finds euclidian distance between two Point classes of same dimension
 */
template <size_t D>
double distance(const Point<D>& lhs, const Point<D>& rhs) {
  double dist = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < D; i++) dist += std::pow(lhs[i] - rhs[i], 2);
  return std::sqrt(dist);
}

/*
 * Finds euclidian distance between Point and axis
 */
template <size_t D>
double distance(const Point<D>& point, double value, int axis) {
  return std::abs(point[axis] - value);
}

/*
 * Print the point components of a Point in ascending order.
 * Prints in the form {x, y, z} with no newline.
 */
template <size_t D>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<D>& point) {
  os << "{";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < D - 1; i++) {
    os << point[i] << ", ";
  }
  os << point[D - 1] << "}";
  return os;
}

template <size_t D>
bool operator==(const Point<D>& lhs, const Point<D>& rhs) {
  return lhs.coordinates_ == rhs.coordinates_;
}

namespace std {
/*
 * Make our Point class hashable
 */
template <size_t D>
struct hash<Point<D>> {
  size_t operator()(const Point<D>& x) const {
    return hash<array<double, D>>()(x.coordinates_);
  }
};

/*
 * Also make it swappable for sorting
 */
template <size_t D>
void swap(Point<D>& lhs, Point<D>& rhs) {
  swap(lhs.coordinates_, rhs.coordinates_);
}
}  // namespace std

#endif  // POINT_HPP
```

Comment: Code updated based on suggestions [here](https://gist.github.com/wijagels/5f7df6cda71697d96a9154b37573100b)

Answer (score 5):

Overall, this seems to be a small but useful template.  However, there are a few things that I think might be improved.

### Sorting requires more than `swap`

While the provided `swap` function would assist in some kind of sorting, without a comparison operator, we still can't actually sort.  This may well be by design, in which case a comment in the code pointing this out would be helpful.

### Consider default constructor

There is no simple way at the moment to create a generic templated origin point (all coordinates zero).  This makes it a bit more difficult to create something like a `distance_from_origin` function that is generic.

### Consider projection operator

It's often useful to project, say, a 3D point onto a 2D canvas.  This could also likely be made generic.

### Do a range check

The `distance` function that measures from an axis does no range checking on the axis number and there does not seem to be a good generic way to add one.  Consider providing a range checking version.

Comment: As for the sorting-point: how would you sort 2D-points or higher dimensional points? It depends upon how you want them sorted. IMO this would rather belong to a collection of utility methods than to the `struct` itself, if anywhere else than the actual application.

Comment: @Paul indeed there is no obvious single way to sort such points, but the existing code provides for a swap method for sorting. It seemed to me that it was worth pointing out that more than just a swap would be required for sorting.

Comment: @Paul: I'm using this point class to construct k-d trees, hence the swap function.  The tree is sorted based on an axis at each level, which is why I had the distance with the axis function.

Answer (score 4):

Very good. Yet making it more generic is not hard:

```
template<typename T, size_t D>
class PointExt {
public:

    PointExt(std::initializer_list<T> v) {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), coordinates_.begin());
    }

    explicit PointExt(const std::array<T, D>& arr) : coordinates_{arr} {}

    T operator[](size_t dimension) { return coordinates_[dimension]; }
    const T operator[](size_t dimension) const { return coordinates_[dimension]; }

private:
    std::array<T, D> coordinates_;
};
```

Now you can compute, say, a Manhattan distance of two points with different component types (by returning the distance in the most precise type):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, size_t D>
decltype(T1{} + T2{}) manhattan_distance(const PointExt<T1, D>& lhs,
                                         const PointExt<T2, D>& rhs) {
    auto sum = decltype(T1{} + T2{}){};

    for (size_t i = 0; i != D; ++i) {
        sum += std::abs(lhs[i] - rhs[i]);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

In the output overload, you can write one line more succintly:

```
template<typename T, size_t D>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PointExt<T, D>& point) {
    os << "(";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < D - 1; ++i) {
        os << point[i] << ", ";
    }
    return os << point[D - 1] << ")";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice, I like the initializer list constructor a lot